# Install net-snmp on RHEL without yum (or any other package managing software)

Tags: networking, snmp, rhel, net-snmp

Currently I'm working on installing the net-snmp package on bunch of RHEL servers (versions vary from 5.x ~ 6.x).

To be specific, I need `net-snmp.x86_64` and `net-snmp-utils.x86_64` to create `/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf` file.

In normal cases, I'd just use `yum` to simply install them but the servers I'm working on has a firewall blocking all connections except the ones specified in the firewall.

I'm also not allowed to configure the firewall to enable `yum` to download the packages online due to security reasons (not sure why, though).

So I downloaded the `net-snmp-5.8.tar.gz` file to my PC and SCP'd it to the servers and tried to manually install it there.

But since I'm no expert on this, I just couldn't get them installed with the information online.

The files seem to be running but it doesn't create the `snmpd.conf` file that I need, or any other SNMP configs.

Is there a guide to installing these packages properly using the tar.gz file? Or is there something wrong here?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you run the `snmpconf` script?  If I remember correctly it should have been installed along with `net-snmp` and it will generate an `snmpd.conf` file that is at least a good starting point if not the final one you'll want.

Comment: I have, and I do have the snmpd.conf file. It just was not created at ```/etc/snmp/``` directory. So I had to manually move it. However, that still doesn't allow ```service snmpd``` command to work :(